# Training with a target value as feature

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I have a dataset, where reagent x was added to a suspension to reach a certain value ŷ, which was set before the experiment.
The actually measured value was y, which is my target value.

My question is now, can I use ŷ and x (among others) for training to predict y?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that limits which features you should use for prediction are which features *you actually expect to have* when making a prediction. If there are scenarios where you will know y-hat and x but not y, then it's fine to predict y using those two values. If there is no scenario where you will know y-hat but not y, then it does not make sense to use y-hat as a predictor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
y-hat is known, as this value should be reached. x is then estimated to reach y-hat, so those values are known, but somehow correlated. 
The finally measured value y is not known. So I use x and y-hat (and others) to predict y. 
The final goal is to adjust the amount of x in a way that the real value y matches y-hat.

Comment: @user11708656 Would you adjust y-hat, though? The way I understand, you want to predict some final measure (say concentration) y based on the amount of input reagent x. I don't really see how whatever concentration you're targeting has any effect on what x amount of reagent actually does. It sounds like if you know x, y-hat is irrelevant. Some quantity of reagent will yield some concentration, regardless of what your target concentration is. It's not technically wrong to include it in the model, but I'm not sure it carries information beyond what x already tells you.

Comment: I would absolutely agree, but it actually improves the model a lot. I'm using a simple linear regression model, due to it's interpretability . I can only assume that the addition of y-hat tackles the problem of non-linear behaviour at higher y-values... But if it's in principle valid to include y-hat, I'm pretty happy :)